# how to grep a pattern containing a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I can't seem to get the syntax right:
I want grep to count the lines which start with a "0" and contain the phrase in the variable "phrase"

I tried:

```
cut -f1,5 file.txt|grep -c 0*${phrase}*
```

(the cut is working as it should, it isn't really part of the problem) but it won't work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `| fgrep "${phrase}"`

Comment: @bobah That ignores the required 0 at the start of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0*` is "zero or more `0`" and not necessarily at the start of the string.

```
grep -c "^0.*${phrase}"
```

You can use `.*` to indicate zero or more characters.  Also keep in mind the possible problems you will run into if `$phrase` has regex meta characters.

Comment: thanks a lot, that did it!
why does ^0 means "starts with zero"? isn't ^ used for negation?

Comment: @shayelk `^` is only used for negation inside of a character class, i.e. `[^0]`. Otherwise it is the anchor for the start of the string/line.

Answer (score 2):

The correct call is

```
... | grep -c "^0.*$phrase"
```

The entire thing must be quoted to prevent the shell interpretation of certain characters, such as `*`. The `.*` matches 0 or more arbitrary characters between the 0 at the start of the line and whatever `$phrase` matches.